# Writing to Azure blob storage. Everything looks fine but it creates so many temporary files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks

Followed the code written in this link.
https://gist.github.com/Zifah/ba0c3771069a11ba53969b000b038b82/revisions

It creates so many temporary files. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour when run any spark job to create these files.

When DBIO transactional commit is enabled, metadata files starting with *started* and *committed* will accompany data files created by Apache Spark jobs. Generally you shouldn’t alter these files directly. Rather, use the VACUUM command to clean the files.

A combination of below three properties will help to disable writing all the transactional files which start with "_".

1. We can disable the transaction logs of spark parquet write using

> spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass =
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol

This will help to disable the committed and started files but still _SUCCESS, _common_metadata and _metadata files will generate.

2. We can disable the _common_metadata and _metadata files using

> parquet.enable.summary-metadata=false

3. We can also disable the _SUCCESS file using

> mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs=false

For more details, refer "[Transactional Writes to Cloud Storage with DBIO](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/dbio-commit.html)" and "[Stop Azure Databricks auto creating files](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/20827/stop-azure-databricks-auto-creating-success-files.html)" and "[How do I prevent _success and _committed files in my write output?](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/14712/how-do-i-prevent-success-and-committed-files-in-my.html)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.